# Pegar valor de 2 select , e exibir os dados de cada um

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, ajax

Estou montando uma pagina onde a pessoa conseguira comparar 2 produtos.

Tenho 2 tabelas, categorias e produtos.

Os 1º comboBox, fazem um select na tabela de categorias. Ao escolher uma categoria, nisso, chama um arquivo que vê quais produtos pertencem aquela categoria.

Assim ao escolher 2 produtos no 2º combobox(sublist) e apertar o botão teria que ser realizado um select no banco, pegando os 2 id's de cada sublist e exibir os dados deles abaixo.

Basicamente funcionaria assim:

```
<combo01> ComboBox 01</combo>
<combo02> ComboBox 02 </combo>
<combo01> sublist 01</combo>
<combo02> sublist 02</combo> //o conteúdo das sublists altera de acordo com o que foi selecionado no comboBox
<btn>Comparar</btn> //ao clicar em comparar, faria um select no banco com os 2 id de cada sublist, e mostraria os dados abaixo.
```

Vou colocar o link dos códigos aqui, se alguém puder me ajudar a resolver este problema, ficaria muito agradecido

https://www.dropbox.com/sh/7eupvel35rli2qg/AADJBHRFFprKS1lQNJ06ZcKca?dl=0

Comment: Cara, o `ComboBox 01` e o `ComboBox 02` são para escolher categorias? porque se sim, tu vai poder comparar categorias de produtos diferentes, o ideal seria tu ter apenas um combobox de categoria, e depois que pegar o produto fazer dois selects para usar na comparação.

Comment: Boa tarde Erlon ,Desculpe responder agora , fiquei sem internet ontem. O problema de fazer 1 comboBox só , é que se a pessoa quiser fazer pesquisa de Marcas/categorias diferentes , não daria certo .

Comment: Tudo depende, de para que ele utilizara

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eu faria com ajax, passando os IDs dos produtos selecionados nas listas;

```
function buscaProduto(callback, id) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        url: "endereco/funcao", //substitua pela página em php que acessa o banco e retorna os dados
        data: "{'cdProduto':'" + id + "'}", //vamos supor que você tenha uma função na página acima que espere um parametro com o nome cdProduto
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (json) {
            callback(json);                
        },
        error: function (XMLHttpRequest, status, error) {
            console.log(XMLHttpRequest);
            console.log(status);
            console.log(error);
        }
    });    
}
```

Chamando a função acima para o produto 01:

```
buscaProduto( function (json) {
    carregaProduto($.parseJSON(json.d), divProduto01);
}, [id do produto selecionado na lista01]);
```

e para o produto 02:

```
buscaProduto( function (json) {
    carregaProduto($.parseJSON(json.d), divProduto02);
}, [id do produto selecionado na lista02]);
```

Exibindo os dados que retornaram do banco:

```
function carregaProduto(dados, div) {
   if (dados != null) {
      aprensenta os dados na div informada!
   } else {
      aprensenta mensagem de produto não encontrado!
   }    
}
```

Você pode fazer uma nova função para executar as duas buscaProduto() no evento onClick do botão assim:

```
function btnClick() {    
    buscaProduto( function (json) {
        carregaProduto($.parseJSON(json.d), $("#divProduto01");
    }, $("#tv_assinatura").val());

    buscaProduto( function (json) {
        carregaProduto($.parseJSON(json.d), $("#divProduto02"));
    }, $("#tv_assinatura02").val());
}
```

Obs: note que estou apenas mostrando uma maneira de fazer e não te dando um código pronto, para você copiar e colar no seu projeto.

Comment: boa tarde Dil_oliveira , onde eu colocaria esse script ajax na pagina ? Você poderia demostrar no meu codigo  , não manjo muito de ajax .Obrigado desde Já

Comment: Cara, arquivos com dados confidenciais como nome de usuário e senha, não devem ser disponibilizados publicamente, alguém com má intenção pode fazer um estrago. Sugiro trocar a senha imediatamente.

Comment: Vish , vlw cara , juro que não tinha reparado que as config para acessar o servidor estavam no arquivo , muito obrigado. Tentei chamar sua função , mas não esta dando certo , pelo que vi na net , seria chama-la no botão , assim : <input value="Comparar" type="button" onClick="carregaProduto();" /> ? . Mais uma vez , grato

Comment: Boa tarde Dill , Primeiramente,muito obrigado pela atenção em ajudar a resolver meu problema.Fiz o script php que pegara e exbira os dados,voce pode testa-lo aqui http://www.script-beta.esy.es/functions/call_pacotes.php. O problema é que , o botão que deveria comparar os dados,não esta executando nenhuma ação.Erro : Uncaught ReferenceError: carregaProduto is not defined(index):100 onclick. Vou colocar todo o codigo aqui , voce poderia me ajudar a ver onde estou errando ? Mais uma vez grato : https://www.dropbox.com/sh/7eupvel35rli2qg/AADJBHRFFprKS1lQNJ06ZcKca?dl=0